# Correctness of sentence

Tags: tense

I wrote the sentence "I am wishing the best to you and your family", and I would like to know, if it is correct, especially regarding the tense.

Comment: This *is* grammatically correct, and it makes sense. Yes, you can substitute 'to' with 'for', but it works either way.

Comment: Would you please tell me, what does *correctness* mean in language learning?

Comment: @ghazal - That's an interesting question. One sentence can be grammatically correct yet make no sense, and another can make sense but violate grammatical rules. And then there are sentences that are interpretable, with no grammar mistakes, yet they simply sound awkward because that's not how most English speakers would convey the information. For example: That cake is half-baked. (OK) That idea is half-baked. (OK) That dictionary is half-baked. (Grammatically OK, but nonsense) That, pie will be, half-baked yesterday. (Sensible, except the verb tense and commas are obviously wrong).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is correct and a common way to phrase this. You may use either your original example:

> I am wishing the best to you and your family.

Or this alternative:

> Best wishes to you and your family.

In your original version, you're saying that you are currently wishing good things happen to the person and their family. In the second example, there's an implied *"I send"* at the beginning: "(I am sending my) best wishes to you and your family".  Either is perfectly acceptable and common.

Comment: I'll be happy if you include something about *I'm wishing the best **for** you/your family* also.

Answer (score 0):

Your phrasing is grammatically correct, but it is more usual to see

> I wish the best to you and your family.

The use of "[be] [do]-ing", such as "am wishing", is called the *present progressive* and emphasizes that the action is taking place *right now*. Unless you want to call attention to that, use the more basic form.

Answer (score -1):

Wishing as a verb, honestly I never heard of, rather "wishing" as noun is used more. For example,

> he is now above all wishing and desire.

So your sentence is not grammatically incorrect, but somebody don't wish for a minute for instance, they wish for somebody for as long as possible, so "I am wishing" in this sense, seems awkward. [In fact, Google NGram shows "I am wising" is not at all seen in colloquial usage](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+am+wishing%2C+I+wish&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).

Again, in this case, "for" sounds more natural than "to" to me. To can be used more in situations like, *Do you wish to do something?*

Comment: Actually the OP's sentence is correct, and I don't understand the example you've presented here. What do you mean to say when you write "He does not need any wishing?" I don't understand.

Comment: @WendiKidd, Edited the example.

Comment: You have a good point that *I am wishing* is a lot less common than *I wish*.  I also agree that it's not incorrect.  But I don't think it's awkward--it seems unremarkable to me.  It's not always true that a minority form is unacceptable; sometimes linguistic variation is okay :-)  It's my personal opinion that this is one of those times.

Comment: Also: I voted this answer up because I think it's helpful.  I agree that *for* is more natural, but that's just my personal opinion and isn't intended to be a statement about English in general.  But I also voted up the other two answers, so I guess my votes more or less cancel out :-)

Comment: @snailboat, I don't know who downvoted, but really I am not that worried about it. Personally, I really could not find what is wrong with the answer until you pointed out the scandalous "awkward". Thanks for your helpful comment (_which I always do before downvoting, but that's my personal principle_). :-)

Comment: "I wish I had a new car" is correct, and "I am wishing I had a new car" is less so.  However, "Since we have a picnic planned for Saturday, I am wishing for good weather" is an example of when wishing is more correct than wish.  The reason it's less common is that the context is less common, not that it's a less common usage in a context where each could be used.